# How do I get the BandLuxe C505 working in Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless

I just signed up for a WISP in my area and I can't get the USB Dongle to work with Ubuntu.

The Dongle is a BandRich BandLuxe C505 LTE Modem. I'm currently running Ubuntu 12.10 and the modem appears to be recognized but it never ends up connecting. I entered all of the correct APN information into the Network Manager. Is there something I need to do differently? Let me know what you all think.

**Edit:**
Oh, I forgot to mention that the LTE Modem is being recognized as a mobile broadband device and an ethernet device at the same time.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that the LTE Modem is being recognized as a mobile broadband device and an ethernet device at the same time.

Comment: You should **edit extra details into your question** instead of commenting - because some potential answerers do not read the comments. Please keep that in mind in the future, but for now I have edited it in for you.

Answer (score 0):

perhups this could help you 
http://www.fedaro.info/2013/07/06/utilizar-modem-bandluxe-distribuido-por-antel-en-ubuntu/
its in spanish for ubuntu 12.04, you can easyly translate it online

I'll be getting that device soon and try it in 13.04

so good luck for us both